# What is the server URL thru which Apple updates occur?

Tags: macos

I would like to know what is the URL thru which Apple updates occur.

I need this to setup caching for my Squid Proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Apple KB Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629), ports 80 and 8088 are used for SUS.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has documentation for their Software Update server built in to OS X Server [here](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/) -- see under "Other services".  This doesn't seem to give the detail you need, but it does mention the `/etc/swupd/swupd.conf` configuration file, which might contain that information.